# Event is not being attached on elements which is coming in the response from the server

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have many div named = "abc" on which i added an event listener by their names and they are working fine but when i get those same divs in the response from the server,events unbind.

[image: This is my div]

[image: This is my script for adding an event]

[image: This is the result before getting response]

[image: This is after getting the response]

These are working fine

```
<div class="row" style="">
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 h-col" id="h-col">
<div class=" hero-rows">
<div class=""id="Strength" name="nature"><h5>STRENGTH</h5> 
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row" style="">    
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 h-col" id="h-col">
<div class=" hero-rows">
<div class="" id="AGILITY" name="nature" ><h5>AGILITY</h5> 
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row" style="">
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 h-col" id="h-col">
<div class=" hero-rows">
<div class="" id="INTELLIGENCE" name="nature" > 
<h5>INTELLIGENCE</h5></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

THIS IS MY SCRIPT..

```
var nature = document.getElementsByName('nature');

for(var i =0; i< nature.length; i++)
{
nature[i].addEventListener('click',function()
{
    heroNatureFilter(this.id);
});
}
```

Comment: You cannot add code in question? instead of screenshots.

Comment: Please add your code *as code*, not as screenshots - what if the image breaks? What if the resolution's low? Then we won't be able to fix your code.

Comment: The answer to this seems obvious, but, as others have already noted, add the code rather than screenshots.

Comment: I have added my code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand how event binding works. When you bind events on an HTML element or set of elements, the event is bound to the elements currently on that page. It does not mean it is bound to future elements that were not available when the event was bound.

When your server returns its response, and those elements are added to the page, the bound event handlers do not apply to them, since they were not there when the events were bound. To get them to respond to the event in question, you have to call code to bind the events again. This time, since those elements are on the page, the event binding will apply to them. An easy way to do this is to encapsulate the event binding call inside a function.

In your case, you have to enclose this part:

```
var nature = document.getElementsByName('nature');

for(var i = 0; i < nature.length; i++) }{
   nature[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      heroNatureFilter(this.id);
   });
}
```

in a function, e.g:

```
function bindEvents() {
    var nature = document.getElementsByName('nature');

    for(var i = 0; i < nature.length; i++) }{
       nature[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
          heroNatureFilter(this.id);
       });
    }
}
```

Then, when your server response returns, you have to call the function to bind the events to the newly returned elements:

```
bindEvents();
```

Comment: I have called it like following this but still it is not working am i going wrong somewhere ?

Comment: echo('<script>ListenerForHeroNatures();</script>');